# Prestashop. How to Add order barcode to mailalert module?

Tags: php, html, prestashop, barcode

I would like to take our internal reference number and add it to the mailalert as a Barcode.

I can insert into PDF invoice, with this code

```
<tr>
<td style="width: 17%"></td>
<td style="width: 83%">

{assign var=black value=[0,0,0]}{assign var=white value=[255,255,255]}
{assign var=stuff value=['position'=>'S', 'border'=>false, 'padding'=>4, 
'fgcolor'=>$black, 'bgcolor'=>$white, 'text'=>false, 'font'=>'helvetica', 
'fontsize'=>8, 'stretchtext'=>4]}
{assign var=params value=TCPDF::serializeTCPDFtagParameters(array($order-
>getUniqReference(), 'C39', '', '', 40, 15, 0.4, $stuff, 'N'))}
<tcpdf method="write1DBarcode" params="{$params}" />

</td>
```

but i'd like to insert inside order confirmation mails.
how can i convert order number to barcode? for use in mmy php/html...
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you have several options here. Since I don't know PHP or Prestashop, I can't give you code, but I'd like to bring in some ideas.

**Barcode fonts**

There are barcode fonts which would allow you to embed the barcodes as normal text. The problem here is that the recipients of your confirmation emails probably don't have those fonts installed, so if you can use this or not depends on the situation.

- If you know the recipients of the confirmation emails in advance (as is often the case in B2B with a restricted set of customers), you eventually can instruct them to install the required fonts.
- If you are dealing with unknown recipients, you could try to embed the fonts into HTML. I know that most browsers nowadays are handling embedded fonts correctly, but I am not sure if this is the case with email clients, too. It probably depends on the email client used by the recipient.

Given that, using barcode fonts would be ideal from a technical point of view (lightweight, fast, natural text somehow), but unfortunately, there will always be people who don't have that fonts installed or who are using outdated email clients.

**Barcodes as pictures**

I am quite sure that there are libraries out there which can generate barcodes as images. Nearly all email clients are handling embedded images correctly and are able to display them inline, so this is the route I would probably take.

If you absolutely can't find such a library, you still can generate a PDF which contains only the barcode (from your question, we know that you are able to do that), and then convert that PDF to an image. I personally know that there are many libraries which can do the latter.

Then embed that image as inline image into a HTML email.

**Other solutions**

I am convinced that there are many more solutions to that problem. For example, you probably could output the barcodes in SVG format using some library. Most browsers display inline SVG correctly, but as with the embedded fonts, I am not sure about email clients. You will probably have similar problems with other solutions / formats.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for convert order number to BARCODE image with this script

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146336/Creating-a-Code-39-Barcode-using-HTML-CSS-and-Java

But i have problems to insert it inside a mail on Mailalert.

I tried to insert script directly mail but probabily is should modifiy mailalert.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="code39.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
   #barcode {font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; line-height:normal; sans-serif; font-size: 12pt}
    </style>
</head>
<body>


Input : {order_name}<br />


<div id="externalbox" style="width:5in">
<div id="inputdata" >{order_name}</div>
</div>


<br />


<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
  function get_object(id) {
   var object = null;
   if (document.layers) {
    object = document.layers[id];
   } else if (document.all) {
    object = document.all[id];
   } else if (document.getElementById) {
    object = document.getElementById(id);
   }
   return object;
  }
get_object("inputdata").innerHTML=DrawCode39Barcode(get_object("inputdata").innerHTML,0);
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Can anyone help me please? thanks